# WPF Button is static and does nothing

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm designing a WPF Application in C# and I'm creating a grid with its controls at runtime. All of my controls work fine (Image, Textblocks, Labels), but my Button does not. It just sits there. When I move my mouse over it, it does nothing. When I click it, (w/ a click event handler) it does absolutely nothing! I've tried using different event handlers such as (Click, MouseDown, MouseUp). I have no clue what the problem is. Here's my code for the button:

```
Button AccessBtn = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
AccessBtn.Content = "Access:";
AccessBtn.Margin = new Thickness(397, 571, 472, 41);
AccessBtn.Name = "AccessButton";
AccessBtn.Focusable = true;                      
AccessBtn.Click += (s, EventArgs) =>{
       MessageBox.Show("Nothing here yet!");
};
grid.Children.Add(AccessBtn);
```

Comment: As an aside, avoid using `Margin` to position elements, instead use layout controls like `Grid` or `StackPanel`.

Comment: @Dai What's wrong with `Margin`?

Comment: If you resize your window the button won't be re-flowed, nor will it re-flow with differing windows text size (as text-size can be controlled independently of DPI).

Comment: I would guess that something is covering your button and absorbing the mouse events

Comment: @GlenThomas Like what? Another control?

Comment: Yes. Do you have to build your UI in code? Can't you just use XAML like you are supposed to?

Comment: @GlenThomas Actually, not really. I'm using the same Window for several different UI configurations. What could be covering it?

Comment: Delete all that  and use proper XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add children to the grid. They are added to row 0 and column 0.
So they will all be stacked on to each other. The button is no longer visible for the mouse event. You should put the button on top of the items or use row and columns to arrange the items. (Alternatively you might want to check a Canvas to position your elements.)

Comment: Thanks! Just thought of it and fixed it right before I saw this!